# Let $X$ be an infinite set and $τ$ a topology on $X$. If every infinite subset of $X$ is in $τ$, prove that $τ$ is the discrete topology.

Tags: general-topology

I have been thinking about this one for awhile, but I cannot crack it. I think the proof to this is similar to the proof that the topology containing all singleton sets is the discrete topology, in that that proof used the infinite union of singletons to build every subset. In this one I imagine that some how the use of finite intersections can create every finite subset of $X$, but that seems weird and I'm not sure how I would show that.

Is this correct? Can someone show me where to start?

Comment: Do we have the axiom of choice?

Comment: @KennyLau. We will need it. The 4 answers given so far all rely on the existence of an infinite, co-infinite  $A\subset X$, which is provable from AC....BUT it is known to be equi-consistent with ZF+$(\neg$ AC) that  such  a  set $A$ does not exist for some infinite $X$,. See Wikipedia:  "Amorphous set".  If $X$ is amorphous then $\tau$ could be the co-finite topology on $X$. which is not discrete.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Um, it depends on your definition of "$X$ is infinite". If it is "exists injection from naturals into $X$", then Arnaud's answer works without any choice.

Comment: @KennyLau: See my above comment. Also, the reason people worry about choice is that, if you define "finite" as being in bijection with an initial segment of the naturals, and "infinite" as "not finite", then you need choice to show that "infinite" implies "exists injection from naturals". Amorphous sets are the counter-examples to this in the absence of choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming that $X$ is infinite, otherwise the claim does not hold.

If suffices to prove that the singletons $\{x\}$ are open, for all $x \in X$.

$X \setminus \{x\}$ is also an infinite set so there exist infinte sets $A, B \subseteq X \setminus \{x\}$ such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

For example, let $\{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a countable subset of $X \setminus \{x\}$ and then define $A = \{a_{2n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $B = \{a_{2n - 1} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Now $A \cup \{x\}$ and $B \cup \{x\}$ are infinite subsets of $X$ so they are open.

Hence $$\{x\} = (A \cup \{ x \}) \cap (B \cup \{ x \})$$ is also open as an intersection of two open sets.

Now an arbitrary $S \subseteq X$ is just

$$S = \bigcup_{x \in S} \{x\}$$

which is a union of open sets.

Comment: What do you mean by the notation "X∖{x}" in your post?

Comment: @MatthewRiley Set difference. $$X \setminus \{x\} = \{y \in X : y \ne x\}$$

Comment: that is what I thought from the context, but I didn't want to incorrectly assume. I have only ever scene the notation $X$ - $Y$ for set difference.

Comment: Sir, 'how we can prove' $X \setminus \{x\}$ is also an infinite set so there exist infinte sets $A, B \subseteq X \setminus \{x\}$ such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi If $X \setminus \{x\}$ were finite, then $X = \{x\} \cup (X \setminus \{x\})$ would also be finite as a union of two finite sets. However, $X$ is infinite so this is a contradiction. In the answer I showed how to construct sets $A,B$.

Comment: Sir Thank you so much for your reply and for a beautiful answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint.** There is an injection $i:\Bbb N\to X$.

For $x\in X$ consider the infinite sets $i(2\Bbb N)\cup \{x\}$ and $i(2\Bbb N+1)\cup \{x\}$.

Comment: What's the point of writing such a nominal "hint", aka an answer where only the last step (already present in OP's question, nonetheless!) is left out?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi What is obvious for you may not be for everyone.

Comment: My point is that your hint already contains the most important step of the proof. I think your approach is actively harmful.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi So what would you have written? Imho there are a number of details that are left to the OP here...

Comment: If I had to write a hint, which I don't want to? "Try to prove that any singleton is open by considering well-chosen intersections." Now that's a hint and not a full proof disguised at a hint. OP already knows that if all singletons are open then the space is discrete. The only "detail" left in your proof is "take the intersection".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi That's also a nice hint. What is a detail is just as subjective as what is obvious though. Take into account that it takes some time to ask a question on MSE and look up answers, compared to proving something that you find obvious.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi In addition, this is a Question-Answers website. The closer a page gets to having a clear answer on top and a complete answer below, the faster the search. The more the answers try to imitate a virtual classroom the worse, because the website is not designed to be one. It ends up collecting a lot of irrelevant chatting, like what constitutes a hint.

Comment: @elmer See, I have the exact same reasoning, and my conclusion is that hints should be eliminated and only complete answers should be given.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Oh, I agree with that. Full answers, the fuller the better. But then if you think that this is actually a practically complete answer, then is your only concern the fact that it says "hint" in it?

Comment: @elmer That it says "hint" and leaves out about one sentence from the answer to justify that, yes. It's pointless.

Comment: Good answer..............+1

Answer (score 2):

This is a good start.  Definitely take advantage of the fact that the intersection of any two open sets in a topological space is itself an open set.  In particular, think about$^\dagger$ how you can get an arbitrary singleton set $\{x\}$ by an intersection of two sets known to be open in this space.

Demonstrating that an arbitrary singleton set is open implies that all of them are.  Because the set of all singleton sets is a [*base*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) for the discrete topology, this shows that $\tau$ is indeed discrete$^{**}$.  In other words, notice that you can now write any subset $Y \subset X$ as a union of sets shown to be open:

$$Y = \bigcup_{y \ \in \ Y} \ \{y \}$$

---

$^\dagger$Regardless of the cardinality of $X$, we can always find an injection $\phi: \mathbb{N} \hookrightarrow X$.  If we wish to show that $\{x\}$ is an open set, it may be convenient to construct a $\phi$ in such a way as to have $x \in \phi(\mathbb{N})$.  This way, you can first do the problem in the natural numbers, trying to get the singleton $\big\{\phi^{-1}(x) \big\}$ as an intersection of two infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$; the advantage is that $\mathbb{N}$ has labeled elements and an ordering for ease of thought.  When done, the idea can be transferred to $X$ via $\phi$ (that such a $\phi$ is guaranteed to exist is sufficient).

---

$^{**}$This is a common theme in topology.  Often, you can show that something is true about a topological space as long as you can show that it's true about a base for the topology in question.  For instance, the fact used above was: if $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for a topology $\tau'$, then $\mathcal{B} \subset \tau \implies \tau' \subset \tau$.  Another that quickly comes to mind is that a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ between topological spaces is an [*open map*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps) as long as the function is an open map with respect to the elements in a base for $X$, due to the fact that $\displaystyle f \left( \bigcup_k U_k \right) = \bigcup_k f(U_k)$.  In the same vein, it is sufficient, when proving that a function is continuous, to show only that the preimages of $Y$'s base elements are open in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a point $x\in X$ and choose a partition of $\{x\}^c$ as $\{x\}^c=A \coprod B$, where both $A$ and $B$ infinite.

Then  $A\coprod \{x\},B\coprod \{x\} \in \tau$ and therefore $\{x\}=(A\coprod \{x\})\cap (B\coprod \{x\}) \in \tau$.

Hence each $\{x\}\in \tau$ is open and therefore $\tau$ is discrete.